# Difference between .so and .so.x

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

what is  the difference between *.so and *.so.x and what does X signify and why this is done in the first place ?

Comment: Usually the "X" is a placeholder for a version number, like "foo.so.1"

Answer (score 11):

`.so` is a shared object, dynamically linked library.  Usually there maybe multiple names for a dynamically linked library, most of the names being names for [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_links) to the remaining name, in these names `.x` stands for the major version of the library, or the full version number of the particular `so`

for example, `libmylib.so.2` would be the filename for the second major interface revision of the dynamically linked library `libmylib`